# Numerical errors/inaccuracies in ProductLog

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, numerics, special-functions

**Context**

In cosmology, a fairly accurate model to describe the gravitational potential, $\psi(r)$ of dark matter halos is given by $\psi( r)=\log(1+r)/r$.

```
Plot[Log[1 + r]/r, {r, 0.01, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this context it is of interest to find the radius at which the potential is equal to some energy.

Now *Mathematica* seems happy with solving this implicit equation:

```
r1 = Solve[y == Log[1 + r]/r, r][[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The answer involves `ProductLog`. I can also be done numerically as:

```
r2[e_] := NSolve[e == Log[1 + r]/r, r][[1]]

r /. r2[1/2]

(* ~ 2.5 *)
```

**Question**

But, then why does

```
r /. r1 /. y -> 1/2
```

return $0$? Why does the plot below returns complete non-sense?

```
Plot[r /. r1 // Evaluate, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, why do these two plots succeed and fail respectively?

```
Table[{e, r /. r2[e]}, {e, 1/10, 1 - 1/10, 1/30}] // 
  Quiet // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Table[{e, r /. r2[e]}, {e, 1/10, 1 - 1/10, 1/50}]//Quiet // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For the first problematic plot, the issue seems to be `WorkingPrecision`. Set it to `$MachinePrecision` to resolve the problem. The other cases seem to be more subtle, perhaps to do with an inconsistent choice of branches in different evaluations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Result depends on branch cuts of *Mathematica* functions

```
r1 = Solve[y == Log[1 + r]/r, r]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> ```
> {{r -> (-y - ProductLog[-E^-y y])/y}}
> ```

```
Reduce[y == Log[1 + r]/r, r]
```

> Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) {0==y+Log[-(ProductLog[C[1],-Power[<<2>>] y]/y)]+ProductLog[C[1],-E^-y y]}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Mathematica functions. >>
>
> ```
> C[1] \[Element] Integers && 1 + r != 0 && r != 0 && y != 0 && 
>   0 == y + Log[-(ProductLog[C[1], -E^-y y]/y)] + 
>    ProductLog[C[1], -E^-y y] && r == (-y - ProductLog[C[1], -E^-y y])/y
> ```

$0$-th branch returns 0

```
(-y - ProductLog[- E^-y y])/y /. y -> 1/2
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

However, $(-1)$-th branch returns expected result

```
(-y - ProductLog[-1, -E^-y y])/y /. y -> 1/2 // N
```

> ```
> 2.51286
> ```